# How to do a lazy create and set with AtomicReference in a safe and efficient manner?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm looking to lazily create something and cache the results as an optimization.  Is the code below safe and efficient, or is there a better way to do this?  Is the compare and set loop needed here?

```
...
AtomicReference<V> fCachedValue = new AtomicReference<>();

public V getLazy() {
    V result = fCachedValue.get();
    if (result == null) {
        result = costlyIdempotentOperation();
        fCachedValue.set(result);
    }
    return result; 
}
```

edit:  The value being set in my example here from costlyIdempotentOperation() would always be the same no matter what thread called it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not a great system. The problem is that two threads may find that the `result == null`, and both will set the `fCachedValue` to their new result value.

You want to use the [compareAndSet(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V%29) method:

```
AtomicReference<V> fCachedValue = new AtomicReference<>();

public V getLazy() {
    V result = fCachedValue.get();
    if (result == null) {
        result = costlyIdempotentOperation();
        if (!fCachedValue.compareAndSet(null, result)) {
            return fCachedValue.get();
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

If multiple threads get in to the method before it has been initialized, they may all try to create the large result instance. They will all create their own version of it, but the first one to complete the process will be the one who gets to store their result in the AtomicReference. The other threads will complete their work, then dispose of their `result` and instead use the `result` instance created by the 'winner'.

Comment: If the `costlyIdempotentOperation()` always returns the exact same instance value (must be synchronized or something) then I would still recommend my suggested approach. It has the same end result, but guarantees that if, in the future, your costlyIdempotentOperation method changes, you will still only ever get exactly one, and only one instance of the result back.

Comment: if (result == null)  replaced by     while(result == null) for exact output .

Answer (score 6):

Try [AtomicInitializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/AtomicInitializer.html) or [AtomicSafeInitializer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/AtomicSafeInitializer.html):

```
class CachedValue extends AtomicInitializer<V> {
  @Override
  public V initialize() {
    return costlyIdempotentOperation();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This expands the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20147562/1343979) by [@TwoThe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2798291/twothe) on how `AtomicReference<Future<V>>` may be used.

Basically, if you don't mind having (a little bit more expensive) `synchronized` sections in your code, the easiest (and the most readable) solution would be to use the [*Double-checked Locking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) idiom (with `volatile`).

If you still want to utilize the [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (this is what the whole family of `Atomic*` types is about), you have to use `AtomicReference<Future<V>>`, not `AtomicReference<V>` (or you may end up having multiple threads computing the same expensive value).

But here's another catch: you may obtain a valid `Future<V>` instance and share it between multiple threads, but the instance itself may be unusable because your costly computation may have failed. This leads us to the need to re-set the atomic reference we have (`fCachedValue.set(null)`) in some or all exceptional situations.

The above implies that it's no longer sufficient to call `fCachedValue.compareAndSet(null, new FutureTask(...))` once -- you'll have to *atomically* test whether the reference contains a non-`null` value and re-initialize it if necessary (on each invocation). Luckily, the `AtomicReference` class has the [`getAndUpdate(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getAndUpdate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method which merely invokes `compareAndSet(...)` in a loop. So the resulting code might look like this:

```java
class ConcurrentLazy<V> implements Callable<V> {
    private final AtomicReference<Future<V>> fCachedValue = new AtomicReference<>();

    private final Callable<V> callable;

    public ConcurrentLazy(final Callable<V> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws Error if thrown by the underlying callable task.
     * @throws RuntimeException if thrown by the underlying callable task,
     *         or the task throws a checked exception,
     *         or the task is interrupted (in this last case, it's the
     *         client's responsibility to process the cause of the
     *         exception).
     * @see Callable#call()
     */
    @Override
    public V call() {
        final RunnableFuture<V> newTask = new FutureTask<>(this.callable);
        final Future<V> oldTask = this.fCachedValue.getAndUpdate(f -> {
            /*
             * If the atomic reference is un-initialised or reset,
             * set it to the new task. Otherwise, return the
             * previous (running or completed) task.
             */
            return f == null ? newTask : f;
        });

        if (oldTask == null) {
            /*
             * Compute the new value on the current thread. 
             */
            newTask.run();
        }

        try {
            return (oldTask == null ? newTask : oldTask).get();
        } catch (final ExecutionException ee) {
            /*
             * Re-set the reference.
             */
            this.fCachedValue.set(null);

            final Throwable cause = ee.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) cause;
            }
            throw toUnchecked(cause);
        } catch (final InterruptedException ie) {
            /*
             * Re-set the reference.
             */
            this.fCachedValue.set(null);

            /*
             * It's the client's responsibility to check the cause.
             */
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }

    private static RuntimeException toUnchecked(final Throwable t) {
        return t instanceof RuntimeException ? (RuntimeException) t : new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

In *Kotlin*, the above can be expressed in a much simpler way (`() -> V` denotes your lazy computation):

```kotlin
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
import java.util.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference

fun <V> (() -> V).concurrent(): () -> V {
  /*
   * The cached result of the computation.
   */
  val valueRef = AtomicReference<Future<V>?>()

  return {
    val newTask = FutureTask(this)

    val oldTaskOrNull = valueRef.getAndUpdate { oldTaskOrNull ->
      oldTaskOrNull ?: newTask
    }

    if (oldTaskOrNull == null) {
      /*
       * Compute the new value on the current thread.
       */
      newTask.run()
    }

    try {
      (oldTaskOrNull ?: newTask).get()
    }
    catch (ee: ExecutionException) {
      /*
       * Re-set the reference.
       */
      valueRef.set(null)

      /*
       * Don't mask the compilation failure with an ExecutionException.
       */
      throw ee.cause ?: ee
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
      /*
       * Re-set the reference.
       */
      valueRef.set(null)

      /*
       * Most probably, an InterruptedException.
       */
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```kotlin
  val lambda = {
    println("Computing 2x2...")

    val timeNanos = System.nanoTime()
    if (timeNanos % 2L == 0L) {
      throw IOException(timeNanos.toString())
    }

    2 * 2
  }.concurrent()

  val resultSeq = sequence {
    while (true) {
      val element = try {
        lambda().toString()
      }
      catch (ioe: IOException) {
        ioe.toString()
      }

      yield(element)
    }
  }

  resultSeq.take(50).forEach(::println)
```

The above code, when run, produces the following output:

```
Computing 2x2...
java.io.IOException: 93224642168398
Computing 2x2...
4
4
4
4
4
4
...
```

The result of the computation can be re-set multiple times, but once a successful result is reached, it is always returned. At the same time, while the computation is being run, the `lambda` can be shared between multiple threads (e. g.: cached in a `ConcurrentHashMap`).

**P. S.** If you're limited to *Java*, you might also want to take a look at the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class.

Answer (score 4):

For a similar purpose I implemented [OnceEnteredCallable](https://github.com/chaschev/bear/blob/master/src/main/java/bear/main/phaser/OnceEnteredCallable.java#L10) which returns a `ListenableFuture` for a result. The advantage is that the other threads are not being blocked and this costly operation is being called once.

Usage (requires Guava):

```
Callable<V> costlyIdempotentOperation = new Callable<>() {...};

// this would block only the thread to execute the callable
ListenableFuture<V> future = new OnceEnteredCallable<>().runOnce(costlyIdempotentOperation);

// this would block all the threads and set the reference
fCachedValue.set(future.get());

// this would set the reference upon computation, Java 8 syntax
future.addListener(() -> {fCachedValue.set(future.get())}, executorService);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can properly double-check before you do the costly operation (tm) by using a secondary atomic boolean, like this:

```
AtomicReference<V> fCachedValue = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicBoolean inProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public V getLazy() {
  V result = fCachedValue.get();
  if (result == null) {
    if (inProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {          
      result = costlyIdempotentOperation();
      fCachedValue.set(result);
      notifyAllSleepers();
    } else {
      while ((result = fCachedValue.get()) == null) {
        awaitResultOfSet(); // block and sleep until above is done
      }
    }
  }
  return result; 
}
```

Even though this won't stop threads from blocking if the value is not set yet, it will at least guarantee that the calculation is only done once. And blocking as well means that the CPU is available for other tasks. But note that if you use standard wait/notify, this might cause a thread-lock, if the first notifies and after that the other one waits. You can either do `wait(T_MS)` or use a more sophisticated tool like `AtomicReference<Future<V>>`.

Comment: Doesn't even show the implementation of the notify and await methods, which of course are key here. Has a race condition which may result in some threading awaiting forever unless timeouts are used...

Answer (score 2):

You just need a `synchronized` block and a second null check inside it.

```
AtomicReference<V> fCachedValue = new AtomicReference<>();
private final Object forSettingCachedVal = new Object();

public V getLazy() {
    V result = fCachedValue.get();
    if (result == null) {

        // synchronizing inside the null check avoids thread blockage
        // where unnecessary, and only before initialization.
        synchronized(forSettingCachedVal) {
            // because the thread may have waited for another thread
            // when attempting to enter the synchronized block:
            result = fCachedValue.get();
            // check that this was the first thread to enter the
            // synchronized block. if not, the op is done, so we're done.
            if (result != null) return result;

            // the first thread can now generate that V
            result = costlyIdempotentOperation();
            // compareAndSet isn't strictly necessary, but it allows a
            // subsequent assertion that the code executed as expected,
            // for documentation purposes.
            boolean successfulSet = fCachedValue.compareAndSet(null, result);
            // assertions are good for documenting things you're pretty damn sure about
            assert successfulSet : "something fishy is afoot";
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

This solution, though slightly more complicated than [rolfl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087250/1413900), will avoid executing the costly operation more than once. Hence:

1. that costly operation doesn't have to be idempotent,
2. thread contention during lazy initialization is out of the picture, and
3. despite introduction of synchronization, your code may actually execute faster.

Comment: This is the right answer for an "expensive" initialization.  Just use double checked locking! As a small optimization, one might simply lock on the AtomicReference object itself, to avoid creating the second Object (and this is a bit cache friendlier).

Comment: @BeeOnRope you don't want to synchronize on the AtomicReference because it is common practice to synchronize on `this` (what the method modifier `synchronized` actually does), and you can't be sure if and how AtomicReference does so, so you could accidentally write a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

As @rolfl points out himself, under a CAS-based approach multiple threads might create their own instances of `result`, which is supposedly costly.

A well known solution is to use the lock-based lazy initialization pattern. It uses a single lock and it can handle well exceptions thrown while holding the lock, so if correctly applied, this approach is free from most complexities associated to locking.